# Room library Typeconverter not working in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to implement `TypeConverter`, but I'm getting
this error:

> Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.

This the data class:

```
@Entity
data class SubEmergencyData (

    @PrimaryKey
    var title: String,

    @ColumnInfo (name = "image")
    var image: String,

    @TypeConverters(StepsConverters::class)
    @ColumnInfo (name = "steps")
    var steps: ArrayList<Stepdata>
) {

}
```

And this is my TypeConverter:

```
class StepsConverters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun toStepDataList(optionValuesString: String?): ArrayList<Stepdata>? {
        if (optionValuesString == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Stepdata?>?>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson<ArrayList<Stepdata>>(optionValuesString, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromStepData(optionValues: ArrayList<Stepdata?>?): String? {
        if (optionValues == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        return gson.toJson(optionValues)
    }
}
```

Here is the Stepdata

```
@Entity
data class Stepdata (@PrimaryKey var num : Int,
                     @ColumnInfo (name = "title") var title: String,
                     @ColumnInfo (name = "content") var content : String,
                     @ColumnInfo (name = "image")var image: String) {
}
```

Comment: How does `Stepdata` look alike?

Answer (score 1):

Storing `ArrayList<Stepdata>` as `String` cannot be queried, but only accessed trough `SubEmergencyData`. If this data should be query-able, use a [one-to-many](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many) relationship.

Comment: I just tried but I still have the same error, could you show me an example please?

Comment: You don't have to mark ``@Entity`` to a class that you want to be ``@Embedded``. Also, you cannot ``@Embedded`` a List. It must be a simple class, like in the example you provide in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you wrote `ArrayList<Stepdata?>?` in `fun fromStepData`. Try changing `ArrayList<Stepdata?>?` into `ArrayList<Stepdata>?`